# HTML Footer that sticks to the bottom of browser unless scrollbars needed

Tags: javascript, css, footer, sticky-footer

On some webpages, the content is minimal and the footer scrunches up near my header.  In these cases, I want the footer stuck to the bottom.  I can do this easily in CSS with:

```
#footer {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Works great.  However, sometimes the content is not minimal and you might even need to scroll to see the content at the bottom.  In those cases, I want the footer to simply come right after the content, like normal.

Is there a way to do this in just CSS?  Do I need a Javascript hack?  If I need a hack, is there a good library?  I'm using jQuery already, so happy to use something depending on it.  I don't care about IE8 or below.  I only care about IE9+ and recent versions of Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Opera.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used the technique described here:
http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

Seems to work perfect aside from the requirement that you know the height of your footer ahead of time...

Answer (score -1):

Since the functionality you require is about having whitespace in the `content` container when the content is less than enough to fill the browser's height, you could use a min-height for the `content` div to make it force the footer to about the bottom of the page.

ie. If your html was:

```
<div class='header'> header </div>
<div class='content'> some content here </div>
<div class='footer'> footer </div>
```

then by applying a css like:

```
.content { min-height:300px; }
```

the content will always occupy at least that height and not stick up close to the header.

You could also try `margin-bottom` for the content if that is more likeable

Comment: Problem is I don't know how high to make the content... unless I use javascript.  Which of course I can do, but looking for a CSS solution or javascript/jquery library.